# 2003 Tarago with Headunit 16069 want to change language from japanese to english

Tags: toyota, audio

[image: toyota 16069 voice navigation double din unit]

Bought a Toyota 2003 tarago with the following head unit , just taking a chance to see if someone out there knows how to change the language from japanese to english. I only have a Japanese manual and I think it will take ma while to learn :.

Thanks

Neil

Comment: I got some white-out you can use ... J/K! We've had questions like this in the past without much success, I believe. I hope we can get it for you, but the odds are not in your favor.